# how to create a dynamic menu in drupal 7? perhaps changing the form block?

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, menu, drupal-7

I have a problem but do not know how to move, so I would advise ...

I want to create a dynamic menu in drupal (main-menu). The current one is ugly, is a list.
I want a menu where there are different voices, and during the hover event appears a little window (with the sub). Or by moving a menu with submenus that are activated at the click of the item.

I have no problem with JavaScript to create anything ...

The real problem is that I do not know how to act to achieve this.
In my case the main-menu is created (I think) from the **module block**.

Maybe I should change something in the form?

I wish I had some of your advice ...
There are lightweight modules that allow me to create menus that? (editable adding file.js) ???

Thanks a lot..

and sorry if the question is too general.

**EDIT**

practically the main-menu is called **#block-system-main-menu**, I could create a js file that runs every "tag li" (menu items), and bring up submenus durnate the hover or click?

You think it's good as an idea? fast? or weight code, slow to load?

Comment: You could either hookup in one of the theme rendering functions to completely redesign the menu's html structure or you create new menu block within drupal itself and play with it like you suggested, by adding js file with some stuff.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89852/how-to-change-html-output-of-main-menu

Comment: @fubbe thank for the answer, but i have some questions: in linked question, i read that the suggest way is a function in php, like you said. But is possible adding js file for main-menu (#block-system-main-menu) and so not create a new block?? I would like to change effects by js and style with css.

Comment: Yes of course, you simply have to add your custom javascript file to your theme's .info file. scripts[] = js/my.js